# MediaController not swiping in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer

I'm using a `ViewPager` to show several Fragments provided by a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. One of these `Fragments` shows a `VideoView` and an according `MediaController`.

The issue I'm facing is, that the `MediaController` is not swiping to the left/right as it's supposed to together with the rest of the `Fragment`. (Hopefully you can follow me ^^)

I've looked through a lot of similar discussions on StackOverflow, but unfortunatly none of them fixes my issue.

This is my **xml** for the `Fragment` that is instanciated by the adapter:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vv_project_details"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is code belongs to `onCreateView` of the `Fragment`:

```
    final VideoView vv = (VideoView) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.vv_project_details);
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri uri = new Uri("some-uri"));
    mMediaController = new MediaController(getActivity(), false); // should I use rootView.getContext() instead of getActivity()?
    vv.setMediaController(mMediaController);

    vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mMediaController.setAnchorView(vv);
            mMediaController.show(0);

        }
    });
```

Everything is working fine, except for swiping through my `Fragments`, as the `MediaController` appears *fixed*... :-/

Edit: this is a screenshot made while swiping between 2 `Fragments`. As you can see, the `MediaController` remains at its initial position...

[image: Screenshot showing that the Mediacontroller remains at its inital position while swiping]

Comment: I also tried to generate the `VideoView` programmatically because I thought there might is problam with having multiple `VideoViews` holding the same Ids in different `Fragments`, but that didn't change anything as well...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I do the following to manually hide/show the controller:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (position == Tabs.NOWPLAYING.ordinal())
                tabPagerAdapter.getNowPlayingFragment().show();
            else 
                tabPagerAdapter.getNowPlayingFragment().hide();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

It needs refactoring though as it doesn't check if controller is actually showing before trying to hide. It matters if you have more then two tabs.